# ssh terminating immediately with message Terminated

Tags: ssh, openssh

I have tried following command on my local system (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS):

```
$ ssh localhost
The authenticity of host 'localhost (127.0.0.1)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is 11:22:33:44:55:66:77:88:99:00:11:22:33:44:55.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? Terminated
```

As we can see `Terminated` word at end of command output. It comes automatically once I enter the command on terminal.

I tried ssh to remote machine also but same `Terminated` word is command at the end of command output and Fail to connect to machine.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't hit the `Enter` key twice? This prompt requires you to type *yes*, there is no default value assumed when you type nothing *(I once thought so myself, and didn't understand why I couldn't reach any host through SSH...)*

Comment: Before typing (yes/no) option suddenly `Terminated` comes in prompt and end the connection.

Comment: Is there anything in your log files? Also you can try ssh -vvv localhost.

Comment: Weird… if memory serves, "Terminated" is what the shell would say if somebody had `kill`ed your ssh. `strace ssh localhost` might be helpful, but is lower level than `ssh -vvv`, so try `ssh -vvv` first.

Comment: Tried `ssh -vvv` three level debug option, but same issue. Terminated still coming in output and closing the connection.

Comment: Tried `strace ssh localhost` out comes like: `+++ killed by SIGTERM +++` last line.

Comment: Please add these logs to your question (at least, the last few relevant lines).

Comment: Hi, same issue here, my log looks like: ```root@vultr:~# debug3: send packet: type 80
debug3: receive packet: type 82

root@vultr:~# 
root@vultr:~# debug3: send packet: type 1
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:
  #0 client-session (t4 r0 i0/0 o0/0 e[write]/0 fd 5/6/7 sock -1 cc -1)

debug3: fd 1 is not O_NONBLOCK
Killed by signal 15.
``` any idea?